# How to run code right when a C# application starts?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, copy-protection

I have put some code inside of the public `MainWindow() {}` but I kept getting some obscure XAML parsing errors as soon as I did that (not on my computer but on 3 others I've tried it on)

Is there a preferred way to run code AS SOON as the application starts?

The theory is I want it to call home and ask it it's ok to start. If it's not, I want the app to close out. Call it a makeshift copy-protection.

Comment: What technology are you talking about? windows forms? asp.net web forms? asp.net mvc? wpf?

Comment: @balexandre, good question. My guess/assumption is WPF, due to the tags used and the mentionned XAML errors and running it on different computers.

Comment: @Lucero, the `wpf` tag was added by me, because of the talk about XAML errors and `MainWindow`.

Comment: What do you call to close the application? Are you checking any of the UI elements in your code logic? What happens when you put the code after `InitialiseComponent()` call? And what is the error you are getting, you can read the InnerException by clicking View Error on your error popup.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, WPF creates the `Main` method (the entrypoint of the application) for you. Your options

- Create a handler for the [`Application.Startup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) event and put your code there. Alternatively, you can override the [`OnStartup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup.aspx) method.
- If that's too late for you, put your code in the `App`'s parameterless constructor (it probably doesn't exist, but you can create it).
- If even that's too late, you can create your own `Main()` method. [There are several ways how to do that](https://web.archive.org/web/20120312143854/https://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/09/how_to_write_custom_main_metho.html). Probably the easiest is to put it in another class and tell Visual Studio you want to use this method in the project's properties.

On the other hand, you said you're getting some obscure XAML parsing errors. Maybe you should figure out what exactly do they mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have `Window.Loaded` event in `WPF`.

But if if you want to check for *run permission* before application loads ( due some resource consuption or some business strategy) use a `bootstrapper` a separate small `executable` that first launched by `mainexe` and after if everything ok a `bootstrapper` runs `main exe`

Comment: `Window.Loaded` gets called even after the `Window`'s constructor, which the OP said is too late.

Comment: @svick: don't see the point of "too late". OP says that he wants to run the check *as soon as* app starts. So there is, imo, a "normal" option is catching `Window.Loaded` or use a `bootstrapper`, which is more complicated to implement, but probably what OP wants actually.