# Find the entry point of a C Sharp application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've got the following c sharp application as a sample for trading an api with my broker:

[Github link](https://github.com/IG-Group/ig-webapi-dotnet-sample)

I'm having an awful time trying to get my head around it, but one of my issues is that I can't actually find where the application starts (I run it by pressing Start in Visual Studio).  I've searched for terms such as 'main', 'static void' and others with no luck.

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the entry point of a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371737/what-is-the-entry-point-of-a-wpf-application)

Comment: I can't really find what I'm after there.  But to be honest, I don't yet understand this language, I thought it was C# (where you have methods and objects), but it looks like there's a lot more to it.  Original question has been answered below now, thank you.

Comment: You have linked is WPF application on github. Duplicate is regarding entry point of those. But you are right, it's not the best one since it doesn't tells anything about `StartupUri` directly, which is used by the simplest WPF applications.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is configured in App.xaml
`<Application x:Class="SampleWPFTrader.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SampleWPFTrader.ViewModel">`

(StartupUri actually)

Comment: Many thanks, I've found that now.  Wow, doesn't look anything like the way I was taught to call methods, looks like I'll be having to learn xml or whatever that is.

Comment: @YesThisIsMe i was using WPF like 10 years ago last time, but yes it is not too straightforward xD