# Manage and load my custom font in single point in wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

I'm working on a C# project and now my task is apply a custom font in all the project. The project is very big and there are a lot of xaml files.
My friend wrote a static class name FontManager and call it's load() method in the constructor of all xaml.cs files.
I want to see that is there any way to call the method once in the project and not for all the xaml files in the project.

Thanks

Comment: It depends how that `Load()` method is working or what's inside that method. You may call it once in `App.xaml.cs` constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the entry point of a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371737/what-is-the-entry-point-of-a-wpf-application)

Comment: Could u  put an example?

Comment: I saw some examples which there is code in app.xaml but for all widgets in .xaml file, we should bind them to the font.